# user defined exceptions

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Are there user-defined exceptions in tsql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own, [custom error messages](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/define-custom-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/390) and use those when calling `RAISERROR`

SQL Server doesn't really have a concept of "exceptions" per se - but you can raise your own customer errors as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

[RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

> Generates an error message and
>   initiates error processing for the
>   session. RAISERROR can either
>   reference a user-defined message
>   stored in the sys.messages catalog
>   view or build a message dynamically.
>   The message is returned as a server
>   error message to the calling
>   application or to an associated CATCH
>   block of a TRY…CATCH construct.

from MSDN